# NullPointerException when opening activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

As soon as I open the activity where my database is being opened along with a bunch of other stuff, my application crashes with a NullPointerException.

I press a button which opens this activity, WorkoutEdit.java, which immediately crashes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class WorkoutEdit extends Activity {

    public TextView mTitleText;
    //private EditText mBodyText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private StrongDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    public TextView squats;
    public boolean workoutA;
    public String workoutState;
    //private double rowId = mRowId;
    public String squatLabel;
    public Button confirmButton;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workout_edit3);

        mDbHelper = new StrongDbAdapter(this);


            mDbHelper.open();


        setTitle(R.string.edit_workout);

        mTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workout_row);
        //mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        squats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.squatLabel);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        squatLabel = squats.getText().toString();



       confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {

            getWorkoutState();
            if(workoutA == true){
                workoutState = "WorkoutA";
            }else{
                workoutState = "WorkoutB";
            }

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;
        }


       // populateFields();

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }

        });



        squats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                alert.setTitle("Squats");
                alert.setMessage("Message");

                //AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();

                //set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(aMethod());
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                //dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        //Do something with value

                        value = "Squats - " + value;

                        squats.setText(value);

                    }                           
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                        //Cancelled
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();

                dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);



                //alert.show();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });


        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radgroup1);




        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                switch(checkedId)
                {
                    case(R.id.rad2):
                        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
                    break;
                    case(R.id.rad3):
                        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
                    break;
                    default:
                        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });     

        //saveState();



        if((Long)(mRowId-1) == null){
            squats.setText("Squats - 45");
        }else{
            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote((Long)(mRowId-1));
            startManagingCursor(note);
            squats.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.SQUAT_LABEL)));
            String squat = squats.getText().toString();
            int squatsWeight = Integer.parseInt(squat);
            squatsWeight = squatsWeight + 5 ;
            squats.setText("Squats - " + squatsWeight);
        }




//end of onCreate
    }
    /*
    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            workoutState=(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.WORKOUT_STATE)));
            squats.setText(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.SQUAT_LABEL)));
        }
    }
    */


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //saveState();
        //outState.putSerializable(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //populateFields();
    }



    //Saves all the data to the database
    private void saveState() {
        String title = workoutState;
        String squatLabel = squats.getText().toString();


        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, squatLabel);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title);
        }
    }       

    public Context aMethod(){
        Context actContext = this;
        return actContext;
    }

    public boolean getWorkoutState(){
        if(workoutA!=false){
            workoutA = true;
        }else{
            workoutA = false;
        }


        return workoutA;

    }




}
```

Here are my LogCat logs:

```
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts/com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit.onCreate(WorkoutEdit.java:166)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
08-04 20:12:27.682: E/AndroidRuntime(23360):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you point out the line 166 in the WorkoutEdit.java? That's where your NullPointerException is...

Comment: Ahhh its this "if((Long)(mRowId-1) == null){" I needed to check if the previous value in my database was null, and the only way to get it to compile was be casting it to a Long

Comment: There is an error of interpretation: "Long mRowId" is not an array. That you can go through and check on previous values​​.

Comment: So, if you found if one of the solutions solved your problem, you should accept it - this is how doings are made on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... your mRowId can be set to null in your code but you don't check for it's null status at the line 166.

Also note that (Long)(mRowId-1) == null will never be true.

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but in line 166 I am trying to see if the id *before* the current mRowId is null, so that I can either set a standard value or create a value based on the previous mRowId's value.

Comment: If the compiler encounters null-1 (mRowId-1) it will return a NullPointerException...

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in Line 166 doesn't have any sense:

```
(Long)(mRowId-1) == null
```

if **mRowid** is not null then `(Long)(mRowId-1)` will never be **null**, but if **mRowid** is **null**, then you will receive NullPointerException as `null - 1` is incorrect.

So you will not get any kind of

> id before the current mRowId

You probably want to use some other construction.